# How do you insert line breaks inside Excel cell

Tags: javascript, excel

I have to parse a csv file of test cases exported from Zephyr for Jira. I need to format them in a way that I can import them into a new test management system. The new format requires test steps to be in one cell separated by a line break like so:

[Cell formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awoFX.png)

Here is the script I have written to do the parsing. The steps and expected results are all added to the same cell but without the line breaks.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Papa = require("papaparse");

// ******************* user defined values ******************* //
// file to parse
const file = process.argv[2];

// ******************* parse csv ******************* //

const parsedTests = [];

// create file object
const fileObject = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");

// set config
const config = {
  header: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    return results;
  }
};

// parse and save results
const results = Papa.parse(fileObject, config);
const arr = Object.values(results.data);

function addTests(parsedTests, test) {
  const found = parsedTests.some(el => el.ExecutionId === test.ExecutionId);
  if (!found) {
    parsedTests.push(test);
  }
  return parsedTests;
}

function addSteps(parstedTests, test, el) {
  const found = parsedTests.some(el => el.ExecutionId === test.ExecutionId);
  if (found && test.OrderId > 1) {
    test.Step += `${test.Step}\n\n`;
    test.ExpectedResults += `${test.ExpectedResults}\n\n`;
  }
}

arr.forEach(el => {
  addTests(parsedTests, el);
});

arr.forEach(el => {
  addSteps(parsedTests, el);
});

console.log(parsedTests)


// write back to csv
fs.writeFileSync("./parsedtests.csv", Papa.unparse(parsedTests));
```

Comment: I cannot test myself, but did you try with `\r` instead of `\n`?

Comment: No I will try that right now

Comment: \r doesn't work either